# Using scene.addRect in for loop. How do I add a variable number to the rectangle's name?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4, qgis

First I'd like to mention that my programming experience and knowledge are very limited. I'd appreciate it if you could answer my question with actual code that I can simply copy and paste.

I am writing a plugin for `QGIS` in Python 2.7 using `PyQt4` to create the GUI.
I'm using a for loop to create paired rectangles in a `QGraphicsScene`. Every iteration gives one pair of rectangles. Now I want to access these rectangles outside of the for loop, but all the rectangles on the left side are called `rect_L` and all on the right are called `rect_R`. Is there a way to add a variable number to their names? I want to call the first pair `rect_L_1` and `rect_R_1`, the second pair `rect_L_2` and `rect_R_2` and so on (or something along those lines).
I hope my question is clear enough. A link to a screenshot of the `QGraphicsScene` as seen in `QGIS` and the relevant parts of the code (I think) are below. Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot]

```
def setupUi(self, Form):
    L = ["Forest", "Lake", "Desert"]
    changeMatrix = [[11, 12, 13], [21, 22, 23], [31, 32, 33]]
    count_i = 1

    #Form
    Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
    Form.resize(600, 600)

    #Graphics View
    self.graphicsView = QtGui.QGraphicsView(Form)
    self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 50, 400, 400))
    self.graphicsView.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("graphicsView"))

    #Pen, Brush, Scene
    pen = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0), 3, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(184, 36, 238))
    scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()

    #Boxes & Labels
    count_valid = 0
    for i in changeMatrix:
        count_j = 1
        for j in i:
            if j <> 0 and count_i <> count_j:
                textitem_L = scene.addText(L[count_j-1])
                textitem_R = scene.addText(L[count_i-1])
                textitem_L.setPos(0, count_valid*50)
                textitem_R.setPos(300, count_valid*50)
                rect_L = scene.addRect(50, count_valid*50, 25, 25, pen, brush)
                rect_R = scene.addRect(250, count_valid*50, 25, 25, pen, brush)
                rect_L.setFlags(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable | QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable | QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable | QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges)
                rect_R.setFlags(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable | QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable | QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable | QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges)
                rect_L.setAcceptsHoverEvents(True)
                rect_R.setAcceptsHoverEvents(True)
                count_valid += 1
            count_j += 1
        count_i += 1

    self.graphicsView.setScene(scene)

    #Form
    Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "MoveRect", None))
```

Comment: Related: [How can you dynamically create variables in Python via a while loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5036700/953482)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list or two.

```
L_rects = []
R_rects = []
for i in changeMatrix:
    count_j = 1
    for j in i:
        if j <> 0 and count_i <> count_j:
            textitem_L = scene.addText(L[count_j-1])
            textitem_R = scene.addText(L[count_i-1])
            textitem_L.setPos(0, count_valid*50)
            textitem_R.setPos(300, count_valid*50)
            rect_L = scene.addRect(50, count_valid*50, 25, 25, pen, brush)
            rect_R = scene.addRect(250, count_valid*50, 25, 25, pen, brush)
            rect_L.setFlags(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable | QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable | QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable | QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges)
            rect_R.setFlags(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable | QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable | QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable | QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges)
            rect_L.setAcceptsHoverEvents(True)
            rect_R.setAcceptsHoverEvents(True)
            L_rects.append(rect_L)
            R_rects.append(rect_R)
            count_valid += 1
        count_j += 1
    count_i += 1
```

Now you can use indexing to access individual rect objects, ex. `L_rects[2]`.